# how to check whether all records in one df are all included in another one

Tags: r

I have df1 and df2, and I would like to check whther df1 and df2 are all included in df3$lbtest. Is it a good way to do the check and mark the one that is included and the one that is missing?

```
df1<- tructure(list(CHMTEST = c("Sodium", "Potassium", "Chloride", 
"Bicarbonate (CO2)", "Calcium", "Glucose")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2<-structure(list(COATEST = c("PT", "aPTT")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df3<- structure(list(source = c("LBCH", "LBCH", "LBCH", "LBCH", "LBCO", 
"LBHE", "LBUA"), lbcat = c("Chemistry", "Chemistry", "Chemistry", 
"Chemistry", "Coagulation", "Hematology", "Urinalysis"), lbtest = c("Bicarbonate (CO2)", 
"Glucose", "Potassium", "Sodium", "PT", "WBC", "Glucose")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the columns extracted from 'df1', 'df2' dataset into a single vector, use `%in%` to check if the elements are present in 'df3$lbtest' column and wrap with `all`

```
all(c(df1$CHMTEST, df2$COATEST) %in% df3$lbtest)
[1] FALSE
```

Returns `FALSE` as some elements are still not present i.e.

```
c(df1$CHMTEST, df2$COATEST) %in% df3$lbtest
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

If we want to return the elements that are present and not, then create a single vector, generate the logical index and use that to subset

```
v1 <- c(df1$CHMTEST, df2$COATEST)
i1 <-  v1 %in% df3$lbtest
v1[i1] # present
[1] "Sodium"            "Potassium"         "Bicarbonate (CO2)" "Glucose"           "PT"   
 v1[!i1] # not present
[1] "Chloride" "Calcium"  "aPTT"
```

---

If we want to check this from 'df3', use either `subset` or `dplyr::filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df3 %>% 
     filter(lbtest %in% c(df1$CHMTEST, df2$COATEST))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  source lbcat       lbtest           
  <chr>  <chr>       <chr>            
1 LBCH   Chemistry   Bicarbonate (CO2)
2 LBCH   Chemistry   Glucose          
3 LBCH   Chemistry   Potassium        
4 LBCH   Chemistry   Sodium           
5 LBCO   Coagulation PT               
6 LBUA   Urinalysis  Glucose          
df3 %>% 
    filter(!lbtest %in% c(df1$CHMTEST, df2$COATEST))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  source lbcat      lbtest
  <chr>  <chr>      <chr> 
1 LBHE   Hematology WBC
```

---

Or another option is to make the column names the same, bind the 'df1', 'df2' to a single dataset and use `inner_join/anti_join`

```
library(purrr)
> list(df1, df2) %>%
        map_dfr(~ .x %>%
           rename_with(~ 'lbtest', 1)) %>% 
        inner_join(df3, .)
Joining, by = "lbtest"
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  source lbcat       lbtest           
  <chr>  <chr>       <chr>            
1 LBCH   Chemistry   Bicarbonate (CO2)
2 LBCH   Chemistry   Glucose          
3 LBCH   Chemistry   Potassium        
4 LBCH   Chemistry   Sodium           
5 LBCO   Coagulation PT               
6 LBUA   Urinalysis  Glucose                
> list(df1, df2) %>% 
       map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
              rename_with(~ 'lbtest', 1)) %>%
       anti_join(df3, .)
Joining, by = "lbtest"
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  source lbcat      lbtest
  <chr>  <chr>      <chr> 
1 LBHE   Hematology WBC
```

Comment: Is it possible to listed out the one included and the one not included, and maybe the extras in lbtest?

Comment: What about in lbtest but not in df1, df2?

Comment: `inner_join/anti_join` is a great way to do it. :D